# Clarification regarding this map reduce word count example?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am studying map reduce, and I have a question regarding the basic word count example of map reduce. 
Say my text is

> My name is X Y X.

here is the map class, I am referring to

```
  public static class MapClass extends MapReduceBase
implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
private Text word = new Text();

public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, 
                OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, 
                Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
  String line = value.toString();
  StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(line);
  while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
    word.set(itr.nextToken());
    output.collect(word, one);
  }
}
```

}

When text is processed by this Map job, it will result into

```
My 1
name 1
is 1
X 1
Y 1
X 1
```

Then after shuffer and sort, all of the same keys will be grouped and we can do the addition for the final count. In this example both of X's will be added.

My question is that, what if I do the addition in the map job itself, by keeping a map of word and count. Then then iterating over the map, and putting the count in the output. Will it have an impact on the map reduce job? The output will still be the same; However, will it be more efficient doing it like that, as there will be less entries for shuffle,sort and reducer to operate on?

Is my thinking of doing the addition in the map job correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you should keep your Map output as small as possible.  Doing preliminary count will reduce amount of data moving through the system.  Note you still need a reduce job that adds the counts for each word,  your input could be split at Y so both "X" words would go to different mappers.

Also,  another good efficiency thing you can do for your MapReduce job is to use [Combiners](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HadoopMapReduce).   These are reduce steps that right on the mapper node right after map step completes.  Thus you can reduce your Map job output even more.

Comment: I am assuming that the input I have given is for one mapper. I might have other mapper jobs with text. So in this example with this kind of input, I should prefer doing the addition(in case of X) before sending it further, right?

Comment: You should always do addition regardless how many mappers you have.   Also,  even if you have only one map jobs you still can have multiple mappers each one running the same job with part of the input.  The actual number of mappers depends on many factors such as the record splitter class you are using (default splitter splits by lines).  Number of nodes you have in your cluster,  and their relative load.